# How do I create a copy of a table using PYODBC?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm using 32-bit Python along with 32-bit Microsoft Access.

I connect to the database and create a cursor.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=P:\path\database.accdb;')
c = conn.cursor()
```

I then read in a table for future use:

```
c.execute('select * from tbl')
tbl = c.fetchall()
```

But when  I try to make a copy of the table using:

```
query =  'CREATE TABLE tbl2 LIKE tbl'
c.execute(query)
```

I get a programming error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement. (-3551) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I'm new to PYODBC but this is a pretty basic SQL line. Any tips on what might be wrong?

Comment: So something like `create table tbl2 as (select * from tbl)` doesn't work?

Comment: "CREATE TABLE tbl2 LIKE tbl" is not valid MSAccess SQL

Comment: @Isolated Correct, that doesn't work. Same programming error comes up.

Comment: You could try "select * into tbl2 from tbl"

Comment: @topsail I get the same error but with a syntax error with the FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of documentation, the best way I found to figure this out is to use Microsoft Access to create a template for the query...example below worked.

```
query =  'SELECT tbl.* INTO tbl2 FROM tbl'
c.execute(query)
```